# What kind of datatype should one use to store hashes?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I understand that hashes will be different based on different datatypes in SQL Server. One support Unicode another not .... so on (also collation)

I am using char(32) as a datatype but the output is weird. 
Using this

```
select HASHBYTES('MD5','MD5Text')
```

gives this ouput:

```
0xA891DB2DA259280A66FD5F35201CAB6A
```

and when

```
declare @h char(32)
select @h=HASHBYTES('MD5','MD5Text')
select @h,LEN(@h)
```

output:

Ё‘Ы-ўY( fэ_5 «j

So I am new to SQL Server.
Could anyone, please, tell me what datatype should I use to store hashes ??

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188362.aspx

Answer (score 155, accepted):

You should use the [`binary`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188362.aspx) datatype. You can use `binary` instead of `varbinary` because the hash function will always return the same number of bytes for the same type of hash (e.g. `MD5`, `SHA1`, etc.). This will cut down on the (slight) overhead required to manage a variable length binary (`varbinary`) column.

In terms of what size to make it, you can run this query to check the length of each hash type:

```
SELECT  DATALENGTH(HASHBYTES('MD2', 'Testing')) AS [MD2Length],
        DATALENGTH(HASHBYTES('MD4', 'Testing')) AS [MD4Length],
        DATALENGTH(HASHBYTES('MD5', 'Testing')) AS [MD5Length],
        DATALENGTH(HASHBYTES('SHA', 'Testing')) AS [SHALength],
        DATALENGTH(HASHBYTES('SHA1', 'Testing')) AS [SHA1Length],
        /* 2012 only: */
        DATALENGTH(HASHBYTES('SHA2_256', 'Testing')) AS [SHA2_256Length],
        DATALENGTH(HASHBYTES('SHA2_512', 'Testing')) AS [SHA2_512Length];
```

And it should come out with this:

```
MD2Length MD4Length MD5Length SHALength SHA1Length SHA2_256Length SHA2_512Length
--------- --------- --------- --------- ---------- -------------- --------------
16        16        16        20        20         32             64
```

Comment: for `md5` hash ( 16 bytes ) why not use `uniqueidentifier` instead of `binary(16)` ?

Comment: @BaltoStar I think the answers / comment links on [your question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49761364/429949) cover the answer to that better than I can.